# WordPress add a list of form items to custom admin page

Tags: wordpress

First of all, I am unsure as of how to properly explain the issue in the title. 
I am making a WordPress website for a family member. One of the wanted features are a "services" page, where they should be able to manually add new services. I already added a "services" menu item; however I am unsure about how i actually make the "add service" page post the form and append it to the services list.

The only tutorials I have managed to find online, are for single properties, not multiple items.

Case scenario:
They want to be able to view a list of services, as well as add and edit new services. Going to the admin menu item (already created) should display the list of services, whilst having another submenu called "Add service" (already created) that allows for one to add a new service.

Comment: Be more explicit in what you want? Like what do you want to show up on what page? is it text, form fields, or links? Usually adding custom fields works

Comment: @TurtleTread I've updated my post with a case scenario.

Comment: And how do you want the services to be presented publicly? I think you need a custom post type of services, then each post would be a service post, then you would iterate through all the services using a WP_Query. But if you add them as form fields, you could check out the Gravity Form plugin.

Comment: @TurtleTread The services should be visually provided as a list on a "services" page. So for each added service, i'd loop through them and add a new "box" to the page.

Answer (score 0):

So currently if the requirement is just to display a list on this services page. You can do it pretty easily by first creating the service page (or any other post type). You want to use a post meta field for this. There are two ways to create the post meta.

1. Programmatically using `add_post_meta()`
2. Use the custom fields which are basically just postmeta just made available on the user interface. They may be hidden by default. To show them, click on the **Screen Options** at the upper right corner on the post edit screen. Then tick the custom fields checkbox. They should show up then on the page if you scroll down.

   You can enter multiple meta values with the same name/key. Say you just want to call the post meta key "service". Just add field with that name and a value. And repeat for more values.
   Then you can fetch the stored values with `get_post_meta($pageID, "services")`. You can loop through the vlaues and display them in the page template then.